# Why do I see errors like 'unknown capability "CAP_AUDIT_READ"' when I try to run a Concourse task?

Tags: concourse

When running a Concourse worker an web UI on my linux distribution of choice, I see the following when I try to run the example hello world pipeline:

`runc start: exit status 1: unknown capability "CAP_AUDIT_READ"`

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concourse uses [Garden](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden-runc-release/) + [runC](https://runc.io/) for its container management and [OCI](https://www.opencontainers.org/) containerization backend. To achieve containerization, certain kernel capabilities are required on the host OS running the worker process.

If you are seeing errors when running a task such as `unknown capability "CAP_AUDIT_READ"` or any other `unknown capability` errors, it is likely that your host machine's kernel version is not supported.

The version of Garden + runC Concourse relies on requires kernel version 3.19+, so you will need to run your worker on an OS which supports this kernel version, or update the kernel accordingly.